# How to print the address of an Objective-C block in debug console?

Tags: objective-c, block

When calling a block, I can print its address by doing "po block" in the debug console. What can I do to print the address of a block I am currently in (i.e. when the debugger hits a breakpoint within the block)?

Note that the block can be anonymous block.

Comment: Are you looking to identify the current block for debugging purposes?  If so the `__FUNCTION__` macro holds a unique name I believe.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks - I would like to "po" the block address in the debug console or NSLog when the code is within the block.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but you can get the address of a *label* using the `&&` [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html), so you might be able to do something like this in any block, named or otherwise:

```
block_start:
    // Some code

    NSLog(@"Block at 0x%p", &&block_start);
```

Answer (score 1):

Typing `frame variable` lists all the parameters and local variables in the frame along with their values, which when executing a block, includes the pointer to the block object itself as an entry called `.block_descriptor`. The value of the pointer (the address of the block object it points to) is printed next to it. You can then do `po` on that address if you like.

I haven't found a way to use this `.block_descriptor` thing by itself in the debugger (e.g. it is not accepted as a valid expression).